# Regex: Match arbitrary number of parantheses preceeding arbitrary word

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of strings that have the following form, where `X` means an arbitrary word

```
This is a string ((X.address)) test
This is a string ((X address)) test
This is a string (X address) test
This is a string (X.address) test
```

I want to remove everything of the string once `X.address` or `X address` has been found (including the preceeding parantheses), yielding

```
This is a string
This is a string
This is a string
This is a string
```

This is my starting point:

```
regex = r"\(X.address"
s = "This is a string ((X.address)) test"
re.split(regex, s)[0]

>> 'This is a string ('
```

It works, but I need to generalize it so it searches for an arbitrary word instead of `X` and that it takes into account 1 or more parantheses in front of the word.

Comment: Use [`re.sub(r'\s*\(+\w+\W+address.*', '', s)`](https://ideone.com/sBjfXJ)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Would it be possible to generalize this to account for 1 or more words preceeding `address`? E.g., `This is a string ((X and Y and Z address)) test`

Comment: Yes, replace `\w+\W+` with `[^()]*\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'\s*\(+[^()]*\baddress.*', '', s, flags=re.S)
```

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(+` - 1+ `(` chars
- `[^()]*` - any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\b` - a word boundary (`address` cannot be preceded with another letter, or a digit or an underscore)
- `address` - a word
- `.*` - any 0+ chars to the end of the string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sBjfXJ):

```
import re
strs = [ 'This is a string ((X.address)) test', 'This is a string ((X address)) test', 'This is a string (X address) test', 'This is a string (X.address) test', 'This is a string ((X and Y and Z address)) test' ]
for s in strs:
    print(s, '=>', re.sub(r'\s*\(+[^()]*\baddress.*', '', s, flags=re.S))
```

Output:

```
This is a string ((X.address)) test => This is a string
This is a string ((X address)) test => This is a string
This is a string (X address) test => This is a string
This is a string (X.address) test => This is a string
This is a string ((X and Y and Z address)) test => This is a string
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to generalize it so it looks for another word in addition to `address`? So, e.g., `address` *or* `house`. I tried substituting `address` with `(address|house)`, but that didn't work

Comment: @TylerD It [seems working](https://regex101.com/r/nMa8KM/1) to me. I'd recommend a non-capturing group though, `(?:address|house)`. Maybe you want to check for the end of the word, too: `\b(?:address|house)\b`

Answer (score 2):

You could rty `.+(?=\s\(+X(?:\.|\s)address)`

Explanation:

`.+` - match one or more of any characters

`(?=...)` - positive lookahead

`\s` - whitespace

`\(+` - match one ore more `(`

`X` - match `X` literally

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`\.|\s` - match dot `.` or whitespace

`address` - match `address` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6X36df/1)

Comment: Substitute X with .+ or [a-zA-Z]+ and that is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

use

```
regex = r"(This is a string)\s+\(+.+\)"
s = "This is a string ((X.address)) test"
re.split(regex, s)[1]
```